# Calculation of risk score based on previous rows in Hive

Tags: scala, hive, hiveql

I have an issue in order to calcalute a risk score based on the previous rows in Hive by customer_id.
I am quite new to scala and hive.

for instance, here is my table Temp1 :

```
customer_id recency_score period_start period_end
a           4             201501       201512
a           4             201502       201601
a           3             201503       201602
a           3             201504       201603
a           2             201505       201604
a           2             201506       201605
a           2             201507       201606
a           2             201508       201607
a           2             201509       201608
a           2             201510       201609
a           2             201511       201610
a           2             201512       201611
b           4             201501       201512
b           4             201502       201601
b           3             201503       201602
b           3             201504       201603
b           3             201505       201604
b           3             201506       201605
b           4             201507       201606
b           3             201508       201607
b           2             201509       201608
b           3             201510       201609
b           2             201511       201610
b           2             201512       201611
```

The risk score should be :

- 0 if the recency_score does not go down between two periods
- 1 if the recency_score goes down between two periods
- 2 if the recency_score goes down between two periods then stays at the same level
- 3 if the recency_score goes down between two periods and then goes down again

This part is quite easy and I have found how to do it, but I would like to also take into account this previous result in the next row, I mean if the risk_score is already at 2 before and the recency_score goes down the new risk_score will be 3 and if the recency_score stays stable then it will stay at 2.

Actually, I don't know how to keep in "memory" the previous risk_score.

One more thing, the number of rows for each customer_id varies (for one customer_id it can be 12, for another it can be 8, for another it can be 3...)

So I would like something like this :

```
customer_id recency_score period_start period_end risk_score
a           4             201501       201512     0
a           4             201502       201601     0
a           3             201503       201602     1
a           3             201504       201603     2
a           2             201505       201604     3
a           2             201506       201605     3
a           2             201507       201606     3
a           2             201508       201607     3
a           2             201509       201608     3
a           2             201510       201609     3
a           2             201511       201610     3
a           2             201512       201611     3
b           4             201501       201512     0
b           4             201502       201601     0
b           3             201503       201602     1
b           3             201504       201603     2
b           3             201505       201604     2
b           3             201506       201605     2
b           4             201507       201606     0
b           3             201508       201607     1
b           2             201509       201608     3
b           3             201510       201609     0
b           2             201511       201610     1
b           2             201512       201611     2
```

If you have some ideas for me, I will be grateful

BR, Sophie

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but it's too long to use a comment and it could be helpful. You can make use of the [window function](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) `lag` to "keep" the previous state of anything. This function shifts the rows by a specific number of positions (by default, one). For instance, this sentence will create one extra column with the previous `recency_score` (you can apply the same logic to store the "previous" state of anything you want).

```
val table_modified = spark.sql("SELECT customer_id, recency_score, period_start, period_end, 
LAG(recency_score) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY period_start) AS previous
FROM Temp1")
```

Note that you need to provide an order (in this case, the period_start column) and a group, in this case, by customer. Once the column is added, you could for instance modify the table with the previous state (although this is not strictly necessary). This will generate the following table:

```
scala> table_modified.createOrReplaceTempView("Temp1")
scala> table_modified.show(100)
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|customer_id|regency_score|period_start|period_end|previous|
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
|          b|            4|      201501|    201512|    null|
|          b|            4|      201502|    201601|       4|
|          b|            3|      201503|    201602|       4|
|          b|            3|      201504|    201603|       3|
|          b|            3|      201505|    201604|       3|
|          b|            3|      201506|    201605|       3|
|          b|            4|      201507|    201606|       3|
|          b|            3|      201508|    201607|       4|
|          b|            2|      201509|    201608|       3|
|          b|            3|      201510|    201609|       2|
|          b|            2|      201511|    201610|       3|
|          b|            2|      201512|    201611|       2|
|          a|            4|      201501|    201512|    null|
|          a|            4|      201502|    201601|       4|
|          a|            3|      201503|    201602|       4|
|          a|            3|      201504|    201603|       3|
|          a|            2|      201505|    201604|       3|
|          a|            2|      201506|    201605|       2|
|          a|            2|      201507|    201606|       2|
|          a|            2|      201508|    201607|       2|
|          a|            2|      201509|    201608|       2|
|          a|            2|      201510|    201609|       2|
|          a|            2|      201511|    201610|       2|
|          a|            2|      201512|    201611|       2|
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+
```

Once created, you could apply the logic you want to your rows, because each of them has its "previous" score in the row.

I hope this helps.